# Is it possible to use URL parameters in If Statements for OctoberCMS?

Tags: javascript, html, octobercms

The issue I'm having is that various translations on the page use URL parameters to fill in the content for a form dynamically. The form has radio buttons and I want to have one of them checked by default depending on the URL Parameter.

So for example, if the URL says `?lang=dk`, I would want the European radio button to be checked, but if it says `?lang=fr-ca`, I'd want it to check North America:

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" class="form-contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="form-platform" class="form-platform--radio-group">
    <label class="radio--button" for="option-na">
        <input class="form__input" type="radio" id="option-na" name="platform"
               value="NA">
        <i></i>
        <span class="radio--label">North America</span>
    </label>

    <label class="radio--button" for="option-eu">
        <input class="form__input" type="radio" id="option-eu" name="platform"
               value="EU">
        <i></i>
        <span class="radio--label">Europe</span>
    </label>
</div>                            
</form>
```

So far, I've tried using `this.param` but it's been unsuccessful so far.

Is my only option to use Javascript to achieve what I need, or is this possible with OctoberCMS?

Answer (score 1):

**For Clarification:**

A url like "example.com?lang=us" is making a request on the server. The request is `Input::get('lang') = 'us'`.

A url like "example.com/:lang?/" is using the Laravel routing system to access parameters of the slug. This would look like "example.com/us/page" and the request looks like `this.param('lang') = 'us'`.

Both of these could work for your system depending on how you are setting the language.

My recommendation is to design your website with dynamic values in mind and use collections like this.

**PHP CODE in CMS page for adhoc:**

```
function onStart() {
    $language = Input::get('lang'); //check for a language request
    $languages = [ //build language array
            'dk' => [
                'place' => 'European',
                'selected' => false,
                'value' => 'eu'
            ],
            'fr-ca' => [
                'place' => 'North America',
                'selected' => false,
                'value' => 'na'
            ]
        ];
    if (isset($languages[$language])) {
        $languages[$language]['selected'] = true; //see if the language request is in the array then set selected to true
    }
    $this['languages'] = $languages; //return languages to the page
}
```

**In your Markup side of the page you can then do this** - With twig you can just make a for loop set the variables and check to see if the language is selected.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" class="form-contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="form-platform" class="form-platform--radio-group">
        {% for language in languages %}
            <label class="radio--button" for="option-{{ language.value}}">
                <input class="form__input" type="radio" id="option-{{ language.value }}" name="platform"
               value="{{ language.value | upper }}" {% if language.selected %}checked{% endif %} >
                <i></i>
                <span class="radio--label">{{ language.place }}</span>
            </label>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>                            
</form>
```